# Trouble in Displaying ForeignKey objects

Tags: python, django

I am having two models Patient and Ipd, Patient can have multiple Ipd. I am trying to get Patient Info in IpdForm Template but don't know where I am getting wrong

I have already tried "qs = Ipd.objects.get(patient__id=patient_id)" , "qs = Ipd.objects.filter(patient__id=patient_id)" but nothing worked, I have also tried manage.py shell to get the objects data but not able to get data using foriegn key

models.py :

```py
class Patient(models.Model): 

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200);
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20);
    address = models.TextField();
    patient_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True);
    gender= models.CharField(choices=GENDER, max_length=10)
    consultant = models.CharField(choices=CONSULTANT, max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

class Ipd(models.Model):

    reason_admission = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    presenting_complaints = models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    ipd_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rooms = models.ForeignKey(Rooms,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    date_of_admission = models.DateField(("Date"),
        default=datetime.date.today)  
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.patient.name
```

forms.py :

```py
class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ['name','phone','address','patient_id','consultant','gender']

class IpdForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Ipd

        fields = ['patient', 'reason_admission', 'presenting_complaints', 
                  'rooms', 'date_of_admission']
```

views.py:

```py
@login_required

def new(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = PatientForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index.html', messages.success(request, 'Patient is successfully created.', 'alert-success'))
        else:
            return HttpResponse(form.errors) 
    else:
        form = PatientForm()
        return render(request, 'new.html', {'form':form})

@login_required
def ipd(request, patient_id):

    object = Ipd.objects.filter(patient__patient_id=1)

    if request.method == "POST":
        formtwo = IpdForm(request.POST)
        if formtwo.is_valid():
            instance = formtwo.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
        else:
            return HttpResponse(formtwo.errors) 
    else:
        formtwo = IpdForm()

    return render(request, 'newipd.html', {'object': object, 'form2': formtwo})
```

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', my_order.index, name='home'),
    url(r'^orders$', my_order.index, name='home'),
    url(r'^order/(?P<patient_id>\d+)/$', my_order.show, name='show'),
    url(r'^order/new/$', my_order.new, name='new'),
    url(r'^order/ipd/(?P<patient_id>\d+)/$', my_order.ipd, name='ipd'),
    url(r'^order/edit/(?P<patient_id>\d+)/$', my_order.edit, name='edit'),
    url(r'^order/delete/(?P<patient_id>\d+)/$', my_order.destroy, name='delete'),
    url(r'^ipdlist$', my_order.ipd_list, name='ipd_list'),
    url(r'^users/login/$', auth.LoginView.as_view, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^users/logout/$', auth.LogoutView.as_view, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^users/change_password/$', login_required(auth.PasswordResetForm), {'post_change_redirect' : '/','template_name': 'change_password.html'}, name='change_password'),
]
```

template :

```
<div class="card-panel">                                                 
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Name : {{object.name}}</span> <br>                                                 
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Phone : {{ object.phone  }}</span><br>                                                     
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Address : {{ object.address  }}</span><br>                                                 
<span class="blue-text text-darken-2">Gender : {{ object.gender  }}</span><br>                                           
</div
```

Comment: Usually, it's a good idea to also post your error messages. It often makes it easier for others to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Patient` model does not have an `id` field, only `patient_id`. An `id` field is created automatically if you don't specify another `primary_key` field, but this is not the case with your model. I recommend reading [the related article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) in the documentation.
Double underscore (`__`) is used to access a **field** in a related model. So I suppose you have to do it this way:

```
qs = Ipd.objects.filter(patient__patient_id=patient_id)
```

Without getting into technical details (like what SQL query is actually performed), this means:
Take all the `Ipd` objects, then take their related patients from the `patient` field, and check their `patient_id` field. Filter these patients whose `patient_id` field is equal to the `patient_id` value you gave.

Also, I suppose this should work:

```
qs = Ipd.objects.filter(patient_id=patient_id)
```

`patient_id` is the database column name for `patient`, and as such is available as a field name. This is [explained here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation).

Comment: i am even trying to get objects from shell , i am getting empty queryset >>> from orders.models import Patient,Ipd
>>> qs = Ipd.objects.filter(patient_id=1)
>>> print(qs)
<QuerySet []>

Comment: Then it means that there's no `Ipd` objects related to the patient with the `patient_id=1`! You can check if such patient exists: `Patient.objects.filter(patient_id=1).exists()`. If you want to see all the `patient_id` values of all the `Ipd` objects, try: `Ipd.objects.values("patient_id")`

Comment: @ natka_m i have deleted patient_id=1 , but with patient_id =2 i have tried query >>> Patient.objects.filter(patient_id=2).exists()
True and other queryset >>> Ipd.objects.values("patient_id")
<QuerySet []>

Comment: And are you sure that there are any `Ipd` objects in your database at all?
`Ipd.objects.all()`

Comment: I have Patient objects and i want to create Ipd objects using Patient

Comment: Ah, well, then that's not the way. You have to use [the `create` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create). I recommend going through the Django tutorial in the documentation, it's really worth it. [The second part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/) deals with models.

Comment: but i have form which creates Patient objects, I have Updated my views.py

Comment: @DanielRoseman I don't have Ipds, I want to create Ipd using Patient object ID in my model form